# How many collections are possible in a MongoDB without losing performance?

Tags: mongodb, collections

I saw that by default, a MongoDB has 24,000 collections available with a 16MB `.ns` file. If I increase that to 2GB (the max), can I then get `3,000,000` collections in a DB? Will there be any substantial performance decrease?

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation large number of collections will not affect performance (almost not).

> having a large number of collections has no significant performance
>   penalty, and results in very good performance

If you need more collection you can increase `.ns` file via `--nssize` parameter up to 2GB.

[Documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Using+a+Large+Number+of+Collections)

Comment: So then what's the absolute max if I set to 2GB?

Answer (score 0):

I think thats the same as another DB... higher, it becomes more slower..