# newbie to mongodb: about initial files size

Tags: mongodb

Just wanted to understand.

I've just installed mongodb to test it on Windows OS. For each DB it creates 2 files: dbname.0 and dbname.ns

these db files have constant initial size (dbname.0 - 67MB and dbname.ns 16MB)

Is it normal and if yes why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is normal - these are the pre-allocated datafile and the namespace file.

**dbname.0** is the pre-allocated initial datafile , which starts with 64MB

**dbname.ns** is for book-keeping.   ns stands for namespace.  The default limit for the 16MB .ns file supports 24,000 namespaces (collections + indexes) (see: --nssize parameter)

whenever MongoDB grows beyond the size of the last **dbname.x** file, it allocates a new data file with twice the size, up to size 2GB. Once the file size reaches 2GB, each successive file is also 2GB.

See:
  http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Using+a+Large+Number+of+Collections

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Developer+FAQ

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Excessive+Disk+Space

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.mongodb.user/49819

Also:

[How many collections are possible in a MongoDB without losing performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521664/how-many-collections-are-possible-in-a-mongodb-without-losing-performance)

Comment: Thank you very much -) one more additional question about MongoHQ hosting. Thye limit db sizes for different plans (16 MB for free plan), so what data size do they count? (I believe not the size of DB files)

Comment: I don't use MongoHQ -- I host my databases myself.

Comment: MongoHQ uses file allocation to limit the size of their free plans. I hope this helps!